# Recommended Lens Types for Scale Model Photography

Tags: lens

I have a MFT Olympus PEN E PL3 camera with the kits lens 14-42mm. I'm into scale models mostly 1:35 armor and would like to know what would be the best kind of lens for this camera for my hobby. Or is it more a matter of settings/skill than the lense itself?

Comment: Check this link out, it may be helpful
[DPREVIEW - SCALE MODEL PHOTOGRAPHY LENS](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/28519442)

Comment: The choice of focal length will vary highly depending on what kind of look you are going for, just as selecting a focal length for shooting the real thing will depend on the shooting distance/perspective desired. Can you provide some guidance as to what you want to wind up with? Photos that look like the real thing? Wide panoramas with several models in a realistic environment simulating a battle between tanks? Etc.?

Comment: Related: [What do I need to do tilt-shift with a micro four-thirds camera?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19737/what-do-i-need-to-do-tilt-shift-with-a-micro-four-thirds-camera)

Comment: @MichaelClark thanks. I'm going for both you mentioned : photos that look like the real thing which may involve several models (armor, figures, diorama, etc) simulating a battle or war zone.

Comment: Related: [Photo : inverse of miniature effect](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50468/photo-inverse-of-miniature-effect)

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, your best bet would be [a macro lens](http://www.four-thirds.org/en/microft/macro.html), preferably one which can achieve 1:1 or greater magnification, which allows you to shoot from very close distances and still achieve focus. The focal length of the lens will determine your possible working distances from your subjects.

The main issue will be that when you shoot at very close working distances, you get a very thin depth of field which can cue the viewer as to the true scale of things. So, you may want to also look into [focus-stacking](/questions/tagged/focus-stacking) and [off-camera lighting](https://strobist.blogspot.com/2006/02/welcome-to-strobist.html) techniques. Being able to add light to a scene lets you shoot with smaller aperture settings, and the nature/direction of the light.